# Convert datetime format 2020-09-16 00:00:00 to 20200916 in panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the panda dataframe in python below.

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD                  prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    2020-09-22 00:00:00   12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    2020-09-23 00:00:00   12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    2020-09-24 00:00:00   12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
```

I want to convert the date format values in column `Date_YMD` into something that look like this after conversion;

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
```

I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first convert the `Date_YMD` column to a pandas `datetime` column:

```
In [731]: df.Date_YMD = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_YMD)
```

Then you can format the datetime column using `strftime` method like this:

```
In [735]: df.Date_YMD = df.Date_YMD.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

In [736]: df
Out[736]: 
  full_name serial  Date_YMD     prc1      prc2   volume
0  bottle_a   AX80  20200922  12874.5  12927.75  61023.0
1  bottle_a   AX80  20200923  12878.5  12926.75  61023.0
2  bottle_a   AX80  20200924  12872.5  12928.75  61023.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your `Date_YMD` columns is datetime object, if not convert it into
that by `pd.to_datetime`.

Then this would do the job, but it converts the datetime object into a string.

```
df['Date_YMD'] = (df['Date_YMD'].dt.date).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: Avoid using `apply` wherever possible, it is kind of slow.

Comment: `apply` essentially adds another loop - however, what is *slow* and what not depends on the use-case. Here, `strftime` itself is very likely to be the bottleneck, not the fact that it is called in an applied lambda function. My argument against using apply/lambda would be readability - using the dt accessor seems much clearer to me.